# form onSubmit doesn't call javascript function

Tags: javascript

I have checked recent blogs about onsubmit event not triggering the method. Those suggestions were not helpful for this problem.And i've tried this method and form in an another html page which didn't work either.So i am not able to find out where main problem is ?
My code :

```
<div id="_div2">
<center>
<div class="contianer">

<script type="text/javascript">
function formValidation ()
{
    var fName =document.Log.firstName.value;
    var lName =document.Log.lastName.value;
    var pName =document.Log.penName.value;
    var email =document.Log.email.value;
    var password=document.Log.password.value;
    var confirmPassword=document.Log.confirmPassword.value;
    var status=false;
    if(fName.length<1)
    {
        document.getElementById("firstNameLoc").innerHTML=
        "<img src='Resource/unchecked.gif'/>Please Enter your First Name";
        status=false;
    }
    else 
    {
        document.getElementById("firstNameLoc").innerHTML=
        "<img src="Resource/checked.png"/>Please Enter your First Name";
        status=true;
    }
    return status;
}
</script>


<form name="Log" action="SignUpInsert.php" method="post" onsubmit="return formValidation();return false;">
<label><b>First Name</b></label><span id="firstNameLoc"></span><br>
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter your Last Name"  name="firstName"><br>
<label><b>Last Name</b></label><span id="lastNameLoc"></span><br>
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter your Last Name" name="lastName"><br>
<label><b>Pen Name</b></label><span id="penNameLoc"></span><br>
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter your Unique Pen Name" name="penName"><br>
<label><b>Email</b></label><span id="emailLoc"></span><br>
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter your Email" name="email"><br>
<label><b>Password</b></label><span id="passwordLoc"></span><br>
<input type="password" placeholder="Enter your Password" name="password"><br>
<label><b>Confirm Password</b></label><span id="confirmPasswordLoc"></span><br>
<input type="password" placeholder="Enter your Password Again" name="confirmPassword"><br>
<input type="submit" title="Done?" value="Sign Up"><br>

<div class ="contianer">
<button type="button" class="cancelBtn" title="Go Back" onclick="location.href='Main.html'">Cancel</button>
</div>

</form>
</div>
</center>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you almost done. simple `quotes` problem.you could change like this in your `dom` else statement

```
document.getElementById("firstNameLoc").innerHTML = '<img src="Resource/checked.png"/>Please Enter your First Name';
```

```js
function formValidation() {
  var fName = document.Log.firstName.value;
  var lName = document.Log.lastName.value;
  var pName = document.Log.penName.value;
  var email = document.Log.email.value;
  var password = document.Log.password.value;
  var confirmPassword = document.Log.confirmPassword.value;
  var status = false;
  if (fName.length < 1) {
    document.getElementById("firstNameLoc").innerHTML =
      "<img src='Resource/unchecked.gif'/>Please Enter your First Name";
    status = false;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("firstNameLoc").innerHTML = '<img src="Resource/checked.png"/>Done..!';
    status = true;
  }
  return status;
}
```

```html
<div id="_div2">
  <center>
    <div class="contianer">


      <form name="Log" action="SignUpInsert.php" method="post" onsubmit="return formValidation();return false;">
        <label><b>First Name</b></label><span id="firstNameLoc"></span><br>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your Last Name" name="firstName"><br>
        <label><b>Last Name</b></label><span id="lastNameLoc"></span><br>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your Last Name" name="lastName"><br>
        <label><b>Pen Name</b></label><span id="penNameLoc"></span><br>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your Unique Pen Name" name="penName"><br>
        <label><b>Email</b></label><span id="emailLoc"></span><br>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your Email" name="email"><br>
        <label><b>Password</b></label><span id="passwordLoc"></span><br>
        <input type="password" placeholder="Enter your Password" name="password"><br>
        <label><b>Confirm Password</b></label><span id="confirmPasswordLoc"></span><br>
        <input type="password" placeholder="Enter your Password Again" name="confirmPassword"><br>
        <input type="submit" title="Done?" value="Sign Up"><br>

        <div class="contianer">
          <button type="button" class="cancelBtn" title="Go Back" onclick="location.href='Main.html'">Cancel</button>
        </div>

      </form>
    </div>
  </center>
```

Comment: oh...are you fixed the `quotes` problems.

Comment: @Anim welcome ..Don't forget to mark as a answer .its helpfull for future visitors.Happy coding (-: