# How to prevent form from submiting until the neccesary fields are fiiled

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I have a questionaire website, that has about 30 qustions, the website is such  that it, displays one question at a time.You only go to the next question when you press the next button.

I have a problem, when I click the next button, the form automatically sends submits the form to the php_script, which then submits the data to the database,

Below is the jquery file that enbales the form to show one question at a time. But the problem is when the next button(which is within the form element) is clicked, the form submits, even when the other mandatory fields are empty.

On the database I end up having the first response and the rest are null or zeros

I would greatly appreciate your efforts in helping me.I do not know what to do now

```
 var q = 1;
$(document).ready(function() {
  var selectedOption = $('input[name=options]:checked').val();
$(".questions").hide();
$("#question1").show();

$("#next").click(function() {

  $("#question" + q).hide();
   q = q + 1;
  if(q > 30) {
    $("#next").remove();
    $("body").append("<input type='submit' value='Submit'>");
  } else {
    $("#question" + q).show();
  }
});

if ((selectedOption == '')){
e.preventDefault();
}
```

});

Comment: Please show where this JavaScript falls within the page and the HTML as well.

Comment: `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43719522/form-onsubmit-doesnt-call-javascript-function` , look at this answer , it will helpful to you

Comment: I would not use client verification to check for this as the client could disable it and your verification would be useless in that case

Comment: @chiragpatel The OP isn't using the submit event of the form in the first place. That is the actual issue.

Comment: @Louis-RochTessier Client side validation should be used, but it should not be the only form of validation. It should be followed up with server-side validation.

Comment: @ScottMarcus yeah you are right, but it seems he only does client side code in what i can see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I re-invented the wheel a bit, the original code was a bit vague on the html aspect, so I splurged and wrote how I would accomplish something similar with heavy reliance on jQuery and event handlers.  Also no submit buttons, handle that with jQuery.

Index.html

```js
    $(function() {
 
 // Namespace to not pollute, be good to your browser environment, but still allow access from the outside
 window.QUESTIONS = window.QUESTIONS || {};
 
 // Save references, because it's not my memory, but my time
 QUESTIONS.form = $('#questionForm')
 // Disable everything from the start
 QUESTIONS.next = $('#next').prop('disabled', true);
 QUESTIONS.previous = $('#previous').prop('disabled', true);
 QUESTIONS.complete = $('#complete').prop('disabled', true);
 // We start at 1
 QUESTIONS.position = 1;
 QUESTIONS.max = 3; // Could compute this with jquery, but this is an example
 QUESTIONS.current = undefined; // The current question jquery reference
 
 // Never auto submit, but we have a way around this ;)
 QUESTIONS.form.submit (function() {
  return false; 
 });
 
 // Hide everything
 $(".question", QUESTIONS.form).hide();
  
 function checkButtons() {
  var checked = QUESTIONS.current && $('input[type=radio]:checked', QUESTIONS.current).length == 1;
  
  // Complete
  if (checked && QUESTIONS.position == QUESTIONS.max) { // Only check if set
   QUESTIONS.complete.prop('disabled', false);
  } else {
   QUESTIONS.complete.prop('disabled', true);
  }
  
  // Next
  if (checked && QUESTIONS.position < QUESTIONS.max) { // Only check if set
   QUESTIONS.next.prop('disabled', false);
  } else {
   QUESTIONS.next.prop('disabled', true);
  }
 }
 
 function activateQuestion(position) {
  // Hide the old question
  if (QUESTIONS.current) {
   QUESTIONS.current.hide();
  }
  // Save the position
  QUESTIONS.position = position - 0;
  
  // Save the reference
  QUESTIONS.current = $('.question[questionIndex=' + QUESTIONS.position + ']', QUESTIONS.form).show();
  
  // Can we go back?
  QUESTIONS.previous.prop('disabled', !(QUESTIONS.position > 1));
  
  // setup buttons
  checkButtons();
 }
 
 QUESTIONS.form.on('click', 'input[type=radio]', function(){
  // When I check something, work on buttons
  checkButtons();
 });
 
 // Stop enter from submitting
 $('.question input[type=radio]', QUESTIONS.form).keypress(function(e) {
  if(e.which == 13) {
   e.preventDefault();
  }
 });
 
 // Next event
 QUESTIONS.next.click(function() {
  activateQuestion(QUESTIONS.position + 1)
 });
 
 // Previous event
 QUESTIONS.previous.click(function() {
  activateQuestion(QUESTIONS.position - 1)
 });

 QUESTIONS.complete.click(function(){
  QUESTIONS.form[0].submit();
 });
 // Show the first
 activateQuestion(1);
 
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <form action="somewhere.php" id="questionForm" method="POST">
   <div class="questions">
   
    <div class="question" questionIndex="1">
     <h1>Question Title 1</h1>
     <p>
     <input type="radio" name="question1" id="question1_1" value="A"/> <label for="question1_1">Answer A</label>
     </p>
     <p>
     <input type="radio" name="question1" id="question1_2" value="B"/> <label for="question1_2">Answer B</label>
     </p>
     <p>
     <input type="radio" name="question1" id="question1_3" value="C"/> <label for="question1_3">Answer C</label>
     </p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="question" questionIndex="2">
     <h1>Question Title 2</h1>
     <p>
     <input type="radio" name="question2" id="question2_1" value="A"/> <label for="question2_1">Answer A</label>
     </p>
     <p>
     <input type="radio" name="question2" id="question2_2" value="B"/> <label for="question2_2">Answer B</label>
     </p>
     <p>
     <input type="radio" name="question2" id="question2_3" value="C"/> <label for="question2_3">Answer C</label>
     </p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="question" questionIndex="3">
     <h1>Question Title 3</h1>
     <p>
     <input type="radio" name="question3" id="question3_1" value="A"/> <label for="question3_1">Answer A</label>
     </p>
     <p>
     <input type="radio" name="question3" id="question3_2" value="B"/> <label for="question3_2">Answer B</label>
     </p>
     <p>
     <input type="radio" name="question3" id="question3_3" value="C"/> <label for="question3_3">Answer C</label>
     </p>
    </div>
   
    <button id="previous">Previous</button>
    <button id="next">Next</button>
    <button id="complete">Complete</button>
   
   </div>
  </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your current validation code is within:

```
$(document).ready(...)
```

Which executes at soon as the browser has parsed all the HTML. That is not the correct time to validate form elements.

You need to have this logic in your `<form>` element's `submit` event so that you can validate the form elements at the right time and then your `e.preventDefault()` will potentially cancel the `submit` event.

Additionally, don't set variables equal to the value of a property of your HTML elements, as you are doing with this line:

```
var selectedOption = $('input[name=options]:checked').val();
```

Because this will store just the value of the element at that moment in time. When the value changes later, your variable won't have that data.

Even if you had these things correct, your actual event cancellation code of:

```
e.preventDefault();
```

Wouldn't work because you have not captured the event object reference as an event handling function argument. `e` would be `undefined`.

This is more of the structure you should be using (see comments inline for details):

```
var q = 1;
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".questions").hide();
  $("#question1").show();

  $("#next").click(function() {

    $("#question" + q).hide();
     q++;
    if(q > 30) {
      $("#next").remove();
      $("body").append("<input type='submit' value='Submit'>");
    } else {
      $("#question" + q).show();
    }
  });

  // Set up the form's submit event handler. If you want to access the
  // event within that function, you need to set up the function to 
  // bind the event to an event argument (e in this case).
  $(form).on("submit", function(e){

     var selectedOption = $('input[name=options]:checked');

     // Do your validation
     if ((selectedOption.val() == '')){
       e.preventDefault();   // Cancel the current event
       e.stopPropagation();  // Stop the current event from propagating
     }

  });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

EDIT 3:

Modified example to hide previous question so only one question at a time is being shown.

EDIT 2:

As pointed out by Scott Marcus I'll move the event handlers inside `.ready`

Moved the `.next` button handler outside the `.document.ready` handler and also added a .submit form handler so you can handle the form submission right there.

This will help you have a single point of code to manage all your form submission situations (validations, messages, clean up, etc.)

```
$("[id^='question']").each(function(i){
```

In the previouse line of code we are checking every question that starts with the name question (it matches question1, question2, question3, question11, questionXX, etc.) and for each one of them we test their value (text entered by the user, if ANY of those questions is empty you will prevent the form submission with `e.preventDefault();` if everything is correct you just let them submit the form.

```js
var q = 1;
$(document).ready(function() {
$("[id^='question']").hide();
$("#question1").show();

$("#next").click(function() {
  $("#question" + q).show();
  q = q + 1;
  if(q > 4) {
    $("#question" + (q-1)).hide();
    $("#question" + q).show();
    $("#next").remove();
    $("#f1").append("<input type='submit' value='Submit'>");
    
  } else {
    $("#question" + q).show();
    $("#question" + (q-1)).hide();
  }

  
});


$('#f1').submit(function(e){
    //var selectedOption = $('input[name=options]:checked').val();
  //if ((selectedOption == '')){
  //  e.preventDefault();
  //}
  // Check that all 5 inputs have text
  $("[id^='question']").each(function(i){
      if($(this).val() == ''){
        alert('Question ' + $(this).prop('id') + ' is empty!');
        e.preventDefault();
      }
  });
  
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="f1">
<div class="questions">
<input type="text" id="question1" />
<input type="text" id="question2" />
<input type="text" id="question3" />
<input type="text" id="question4" />
<input type="text" id="question5" />
<!--
<input type="text" id="question6" />
<input type="text" id="question7" />
<input type="text" id="question8" />
<input type="text" id="question9" />
<input type="text" id="question10" />
-->
</div>

<input type="button" id="next" value="Next" />
</form>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: To whoever: Thanks for the down vote with no comment!

Comment: I would think that it's because just as you didn't appreciate that no comment was left to explain why the down vote happened, someone else didn't find your answer a good one since it doesn't provided any commentary on what the problem was and why your solution fixes it.

Comment: That makes sense, I'll add a comment to it. Thanks for your input!

Comment: FYI: Unless your entire script is located at the end of the page, all of the event binding code should be inside `document.ready`, otherwise the queries that attempt to find the `#next`and `#f1` will run before the DOM is loaded and  there will be errors.

Comment: great code @ProgrammerV5, I appreciate your great effort in helping me. In the code,  I would like to know Sir, if it is possible to remove the previous question, when the new one displays? If yes, how can that be implemented?

Comment: No problem, code modified, now only one question at a time is shown.